# Open Source Voice Recognization Library in Java

Tags: java

Is there any Open Source Voice Recognization Library in Java?

Comment: Do you want to understand the voice or just recognize the speaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Sphinx-4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/)

It has been tested on Solaris, OS X, Linux and Win32 operating systems.

You'll need JDK 6 or better, Ant 1.6 or better and subversion is recommended.

It has a series of demos to run/look at which should help get you started.

Comment: Have you usage experience to share?

Comment: No, but they asked if there was one and there is. No one else has answered either, so 1 answer pointing it out is better than no answer. If you have more to add, feel free to click the edit button...

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSAPI java Speech Api using FreeTTS.........

Comment: I think that it's not possible to do voice recognization with FreeTTS according to this [link](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php#where_is_recognizer)